# QRegExp que permita TODO a excepción de espacios en blanco

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, pyqt5, pyqt

Estoy realizando verificaciones, en este caso necesito que el usuario pueda ingresar cualquier CUALQUIER caracter, con excepcion del espacio en blanco.
Es en especifico para el email.

Tengo una hecha, pero no controla espacios en blanco, asique solo quiero evitar que el mismo pueda ingresar dicho caracter.
Hay alguna QRegExp que permita realizar dicha tarea?

Comment: Por que no nos enseñas la expresion que ya tienes hecha? Asi podremos ayudarte mejor :)

Comment: Porque no tengo una QRegExp, es solo una condición que dice que tiene que tener el @ y el .xxx, no es una QRegExp :(

Comment: Entiendo lo que dices pero "pedir" algo sin mostrar nada que indique que te has estrujado el cerebro para conseguirlo va a derivar en que pocos usuarios te quieran ayudar entiendes? He buscado en google y veo varias preguntas que te puedan interesar [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7151692/qt-4-7-qregexp-email-address-validation?rq=1) ,  [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8022530/how-to-check-for-valid-email-address).Si te sirve avisame y la pongo como respuesta

Comment: Entiendo, tengo por ejemplo esto:
letras_numeros_espacio = QRegExp("[A-Za-z0-9_ÑñÁáÉéÍíÓóÚú ]+")
que lo que hace es permitir la entrada de mayusculas minusculas vocales con acento numeros y la letra Ñ, pero no espacios. El problema es que esto para el email no sirve puesto que el email contiene caracteres especiales tambien

Comment: te he hecho una pequeña edicion(esta a la espera) que contiene lo que has puesto en tu comentario eres libre de borrar / añadir lo que quieras

Comment: validar_mail = QRegExp("[^ ]+") así lo solucioné

Comment: Si eso soluciona tu pregunta no olvides en escribir tu propia respuesta y darla como aceptada! Un saludo :)

Comment: La expresión que acepta cualquier cosa menos espacios en blanco es `"\S+"` (la ese mayúscula).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
validar_email = QRegExp("[^ ]+")
validar_mail = QRegExpValidator(validar_email)
self.line_email.setValidator(validar_mail)
```

Así lo solucioné. Saludos!

Comment: ¿La expresión `QRegExp("\S+")` no funcionaría también?

Comment: Es probable, yo probé la anterior y funciona correctamente.